# angular result and digest in code

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple controller, i want to get a random value on loading, then use it to paint an arc somewhere, but it gives many values and it paints several arcs. I think it's cause of angular refreshing, but can I just take final value, not all?

```
angular.module("app", [])         
     .controller("Controller", ['$scope', function($scope) 
{
        $scope.sample = {};
        $scope.sample.first = Math.floor(4+Math.random()*3);
        $scope.sample.arc = function(unitstart, number)
        { paint arc using first
        };
        $scope.samle.arc(arguments); 
     }]);
```

If not talking about arcs, just place some element, like shown below, it won't get final value of random expression evaluation, but some value of between of evaluation of it.

```
<span ng-controller = "Controller">{{sample.first}}</span>
```

Comment: You should put your view... your controller seems doing nothing!

Comment: please do a better explanation, i cannot understand

Comment: Your controller name is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$scope.sample[0].first = Math.floor(4+Math.random()*3);


And in the markup <span ng-controller = "Controller">{{sample[0].first}}</span>
```

And see if you'll get any value

I think you need to initialize the array as well in order to be able to access the properties.

Comment: No, it works the same. Why array? It's object, I think.

Comment: do console.log($scope.sample) after setting the data and send me a screenshot of what you get

Comment: From that log some error is happening before the log command,

Comment: I have a more of code, the one that I provided above is minimum. So, i think the error is not in random expression or about that.